# Не могу удалить подразделы в реестре с помощью C#. System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, реестр, null

Возникла необходимость удаления кусочка дерева реестра. Есть некая программа, от неё имеется хвост в HKCU\Software. Я значит лезу туда, а мне эксепшн сообщает, что такой ветки нет. Проверил - она на месте.

Удалить нужно не просто подпапку, а подпапку с другими подпапками, в которых возможны ещё и ключи.

В разделе config лежит ещё раздел data, который нужно удалить со всем его содержимым.

Пробовал так:

```
RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"\\Software\\Program\\config", true);


              key.DeleteSubKey("data", false);

              key.Close();
```

Так же добавлял слеши в конец куста и при открытии и при закрытии. Оставлял вместо двойного слеша - одинарный. Пробовал:

```
key.DeleteSubKeyTree;
```

True, false тоже менял.

Есть ещё нюанс. В подразделе "data" - Находятся разделы, имена которых всегда могут быть разные на разных компьютерах. Поэтому указывать что-то конкретное нельзя (ну и естественно они не пустые).

Отловил эксепшен:

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in test.exe ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.")
Ругается на попытку удаления. Но ссылку-то я задал. Как она стала пустой?

Нужной темы нигде не нашёл. Либо не существует либо вот такое исключение. А вот ключи удаляет.

Comment: а как проверяли? надеюсь не через `regedit`?

Comment: Именно через него.

Comment: через отладчик гляньте где стопиться и что у вас пустое....ну и запустите прогу от админа (если еще этого не сделали). Вы поставили знак `@` перед строкой...так что экран для слеша не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено! 
Добавляем некоторую программу, а верней её ключ так:
    RegistryKey key1 =   Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Program\Config\", true);

Затем
key1.GetValueNames().Contains("data"); Ищу подкуст "data"

key1.DeleteSubKeyTree("data", true); Удаляю подкуст
key1.Close(); Закрываю
Ошибка была смешная. Просто нужно было убрать слеш перед "Software" (зачем его поставил?).

Вот полный код:

```
try
{
RegistryKey key1 =     Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Program\Config\", true);
            bool isDataInRegistry = key1.GetValueNames().Contains("data");
             if (isDataInRegistry)
            {
            key1.GetValueNames().Contains("data");
            MessageBox.Show("Значение существует!!!");
                key1.DeleteSubKeyTree("data", true);

                key1.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Такого значения не существует!!");
            }
}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Перед удалением проверьте, если ли значение, например:

```
bool isDataInRegistry = key.GetValueNames().Contains("data");
```

А после проверки проcтым условием

```
if(isDataInRegistry)
```

внедряйте код для удаления. Это гарантирует отсутствия `System.NullReferenceException`

Comment: Сделал, но что-то там содержится. Вот чего вспомнил. Если объект класса "key" уже был объявлен на событие другой кнопки (она не нажималась) и вот я сново его объявил. Не могли начаться последствия? Key. Close там тоже был.

Comment: bool isDataInRegistry = key1.GetValueNames().Contains("data");  Написал после присвоения для "key1" нужной ветки реестра. На этой строке и вылетело исключение. Дальнейшие проверки соответственно не работают.